# Get Exif information

Tags: c, exif

In my application i need to get EXIF information. What libs are exist for working with EXIF data, withou libexif?

Thank you

Comment: what libs exist except libexif? and why do you want another lib, given that libexif does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google'd result is [here](http://www.exiv2.org/)

Comment: That's a C++ library not C.